# Get user input, validate and update in batch file

Tags: batch-file, dos, batch-processing

Im facing some issues while getting the user input and validating the same and passing it to an other command. Please find the code below

```
:: user input for renaming the war file 
@set /P filename=Enter the war file name for deployment
:: Validating the user input 
IF "%filename%"=="" GOTO Error
:: rename the war file before deploying
@rename "hsa.war" "%filename%.war"
@pause
:Error
ECHO You have not entered a file name Bye bye!!
:End
```

In the above code, Im requesting the user to specify a name for modifying the war file and validating the same in the consequent steps. When I execute the above code even if I enter the name, the execution goes to the Error part of the code and prints the message. Can you please provide some inputs on how to fix the same and avoid the error message from popping up. Thanks in advance

Comment: The point is that your script always will run through the ERROR section. You have to add `GOTO End` right below `@pause`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. When I try to execute the above command after I specify the war file name(specified the filename as "sde"), the below command gets executed. IF "sde" == "" GOTO Error. This condition should return false. But its returning true. Not sure why

Comment: I can see superabundant spaces in that `IF "sde" == ""`. Ensure valid command is `IF "%filename%"=="" GOTO :Error` with **no spaces** surrounding `==` or use `IF "%filename%" equ "" GOTO :Error`

Answer (score 0):

You should skip the `:Error` label:

```
:: user input for renaming the war file 
@set /P filename=Enter the war file name for deployment
:: Validating the user input 
IF "%filename%"=="" GOTO Error

:: check whether file exist (if so, rename will fail) 
if exist "%filename%.war" goto :label_file_exist

:: rename the war file before deploying
@rename "hsa.war" "%filename%.war"
@pause

:: skip :Error label
goto :anyLabelOfYourChoice
:Error
ECHO You have not entered a file name Bye bye!!
:End
```

Add `if exist "%filename%.war"` check to avoid next error message: `A duplicate file name exists, or the file cannot be found.`

Consider checking user's input whether it constitutes a [valid file name](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the response. Im getting the error while validating the input itself.while executing the first IF conditon. . When I try to execute the above command after I specify the war file name(specified the filename as "sde"), the below IF gets executed. IF "sde" == "" GOTO Error. This condition should return false. But its returning true. Please help.